# Intraclass correlation in generalized linear mixed model

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, probit

I am working a model using (resp) (and indicator of wheeze status) as the response and age (coded as zero for children of age 9) and smoke (an indicator of maternal smoking at first year of study) as covariates. To account for multiple observations on each child we will use random intercept (and possibly slope) models.

Suppose the GLMM uses a probit link, and that we want to find a intraclass correlation of our data, by comparing one child $i$ at different ages $j,k$. Let $\gamma_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau^2)$. The end goal is thus finding

$$\operatorname{Corr}(y_{ij},y_{ik}) = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(y_{ij},y_{ik})}{\operatorname{Var}(y_{ij})^{1/2}\operatorname{Var}(y_{ik})^{1/2}}.$$
We begin by expressing $E(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i))$ in terms of the CDF of a bivariate standard normal distribution. By appling the law of total probability,

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i))&=
\int \Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i) f(\gamma_i) d\gamma_i \\ &=\int P(Z_1 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i|\gamma_i)P(Z_2 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i|\gamma_i)f(\gamma_i) d\gamma_i\\ &=\int P(Z_1 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i \cap Z_2 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i|\gamma_i)f(\gamma_i) d\gamma_i
\\&=P(Z_1 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i \cap Z_2 \leq \mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\\&=P(\frac{Z_1-\gamma_i}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\leq \frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}} \cap \frac{Z_2-\gamma_i}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\leq \frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}})\\&=
P(\tilde{\boldsymbol{Z}}\leq \boldsymbol{z}) = \Phi(\boldsymbol{z})
\end{align*}
$$
where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{Z}}=(\tilde{Z}_1,\tilde{Z}_2) \sim \mathcal{N}_2+\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & \xi  \\ \xi & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$, $\xi = \operatorname{Cov}\left(\frac{Z_1-\gamma_i}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}, \frac{Z_2-\gamma_i}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right) = \frac{1}{1+\tau^2}$  and $\boldsymbol{z}= \left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}},\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}} \right)$ for the given ages $j,k$.

We know that $\mathbb{E}(y_{ij}|\gamma_i)=\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)$.
Now, using the law of total covariance we can find

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(y_{ij},y_{ik}) &= \operatorname{Cov}(\mathbb{E}(y_{ij}|\gamma_i),\mathbb{E}(y_{ik}|\gamma_i))+\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{Cov}(y_{ij},y_{ik}|\gamma_i))}_{=0} \\&=\operatorname{Cov}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i),\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)) \\ &= \mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)) - \mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i))\mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)),
\end{align*}
$$
where the second term in the first line equals zero because the observations are assumed to be conditionally independent when conditioning on random effects.

We can then find $\mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i))$ as follows,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(y_{ij}|\gamma_i))=\mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)) &= \int \Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)f(\gamma_i) d\gamma_i \\&=P(Z \leq \mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i )\\&=P\left(\frac{Z-\gamma_i}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}} \leq \frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)
\end{align*} 
$$

Inserting this into the equation above yields

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(y_{ij},y_{ik}) &= \mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)) - \mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i))\mathbb{E}(\Phi(\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta+\gamma_i)) \\ &= \Phi(\boldsymbol{z}) - \Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right).
\end{align*}
$$

Now to find the denominator in the correlation equation. Marginally, $y_{ij}$ can only take $0$ or $1$ as values, thus its distribution has to be the Bernoulli distribution. Since $\mathbb{E}(y_{ij})=\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)$, and the variance of a Bernoulli distributed variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}(X)=p$ is $\operatorname{Var}(X)=p(1-p)$, we get

$$\operatorname{Var}(y_{ij})=\mathbb{E}(y_{ij})-\mathbb{E}(y_{ij})^2=\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right) \right).$$
We finally end up with the expression for the intraclass correlation

$$\operatorname{Corr}(y_{ij},y_{ik}) = \frac{\Phi(\boldsymbol{z}) - \Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)}{\left(\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ij}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right) \right)\right)^{1/2}\left(\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right)\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}_{ik}^T\boldsymbol\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tau^2}}\right) \right)\right)^{1/2}}$$
We use this to compute an estimate of the intraclass correlation between wheezing statuses $y_{ij},y_{ik}$ at ages 7 and 10 for a child with a non-smoking maternal parent.

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(geepack)
data(ohio)

ohio.probit <- glmer(resp~age + smoke +(1|id),data = ohio, family=binomial(link = "probit"))
x1 <- c(1,-2,0) #Hardcode child at age 7 with non-smoking maternal parent
x2 <- c(1,1,0) #Hardcode child at age 10 with non-smoking maternal parent

#Extract coefficients
beta <- summary(ohio.probit)$coefficients[,1]

#Find tau from ohio.probit
tau <- unlist(VarCorr(ohio.probit)) #This somehow gives variance and not st.dev...

#Calculate Phi(x_ij^T beta / sqrt(1+tau))
Z1 <- (x1 %*% beta ) / sqrt(1+tau)
Z2 <- (x2 %*% beta ) / sqrt(1+tau)


xi = 1/(1+tau) #Covariance between x_ij and x_ik
Z_cov <- matrix(c(1,xi,xi,1),nrow=2,byrow = TRUE)

phi_z <- pmvnorm(c(Z1,Z2),mean=c(0,0),sigma=Z_cov)
cov <- as.numeric(phi_z) - as.numeric(pnorm(Z1)*pnorm(Z2))

sd_y_ij <- as.numeric(sqrt(pnorm(Z1)*(1-pnorm(Z1))))
sd_y_ik <- as.numeric(sqrt(pnorm(Z2)*(1-pnorm(Z2))))



intraclass_corr <- cov / (sd_y_ij*sd_y_ik)
intraclass_corr
```

This yields a intraclass correlation of $5.96$, which does not make sense since correlation has to be between -1 and 1.

Does anybody see what I might have missed?

Edit: If I change
 `pmvnorm(c(Z1,Z2),sigma=Z_cov)`
to
 `pmvnorm(upper=c(Z1,Z2),sigma=Z_cov)#Lower limit is default`

the correlation becomes $0.04$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Looks good except that there is a missing $\tau^2$ in the numerator of $\xi$.